# Magento 2 : How to change in order status and order id for display purpose in custom POS

Tags: sales-order, webapi, pos

We have Custom POS system enabled on the website.

Like to append some labels in the order id and order current status for the display purpose only in the POS system not for the website(frontend) order view /admin sales order view.

For e.g. If sales table having **10000101** order id then in POS it should show **POS-10000101**

Likewise for the current status, if order having **PROCESSING** status then it should show **POS-PROCESSING**.

Below is the `webapi.xml` code

```
<route url="/V1/webpos/orders/search" method="GET">
    <service class="Custom\Webpos\Api\Sales\OrderSearchRepositoryInterface" method="search"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Custom_Webpos::manage_pos" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

code for `\Custom\Webpos\Api\OrderSearchRepositoryInterface.php`

```
namespace Custom\Webpos\Api\Sales;
interface OrderSearchRepositoryInterface
{

    public function search(\Custom\Webpos\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria);
}
```

code for model `OrderSearchRepository` which is implementing `OrderSearchRepositoryInterface`

```
namespace Custom\Webpos\Model\Sales;
class OrderSearchRepository extends OrderRepository
    implements \Custom\Webpos\Api\Sales\OrderSearchRepositoryInterface
{

    public function search(\Custom\Webpos\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        $collection = $this->getOrderCollection($searchCriteria);
        $searchResult = $this->searchResultFactory->create();
        $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
        $searchResult->setItems($collection->getItems());
        $searchResult->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());
        return $searchResult;
    }


    public function getOrderCollection($searchCriteria) {        
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        /** @var \Custom\Webpos\Api\Data\Sales\OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult */
        if($searchCriteria ->getCurrentPage()) {
            $collection->setCurPage($searchCriteria->getCurrentPage());
        }
        if($searchCriteria ->getPageSize()) {
            $collection->setPageSize($searchCriteria->getPageSize());
        }

        $isLimit = $searchCriteria->getIsLimit();
        if($searchCriteria->getIsHold()) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.state', \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_HOLDED);
        } else {            
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.state', ['nin' => \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_HOLDED]);
        }        
        if($searchCriteria->getQueryString()) {
            $queryString = '%' . $searchCriteria->getQueryString() . '%';
            $collection
                ->joinToGetSearchString($queryString);
            ;
        }
        $collection->addOrder('main_table.created_at', 'DESC');
        return $collection;
    }


    }
}
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.